# Inverting black and white on a bitmap is not working

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, bitmap

I do some image processing with OpenCV. I want to invert this bitmap (black to white, white to black) and i have some problems with it.

I got this Bitmap after doing this:

```
// to grey
Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, mat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 4);

Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(mat, mat, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 15, 4);

Utils.matToBitmap(mat, bitmapCopy);
```

[image]

This is the result after inverting.
[image]

This is my code:

```
    // to grey
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, mat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 4);

    Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(mat, mat, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 15, 4);

    Utils.matToBitmap(mat, bitmapCopy);

    for(int y = 0; y < bitmapCopy.getHeight(); y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < bitmapCopy.getWidth(); x++){

            int pixel = bitmapCopy.getPixel(x,y);

            if (pixel == Color.WHITE){
                bitmapCopy.setPixel(x, y, Color.BLACK);
            } else {
                bitmapCopy.setPixel(x, y, Color.WHITE);
            }
        }
    }
```

The white lines from the first image should be inverted to black lines, but it´s not working. I checked the file with Adobe Photoshop. When i point at a white area of the image it shows that the color is white (#FFFFFF).

What am i missing? Can anybody enlighten me?

Comment: It's not clear which image belongs to which set of code. Did you leave out the original image? That's kind of important. I'm guessing the first image in the OP is inverted from the original. That's what 'THRESH_BINARY_INV' does. I'm guessing the second image is what you get after applying the nested loop. The nested loop should recover the original image. What confuses me is the color depth. `cvtColor` should probably have 0 (auto) or 1 as the last argument instead of 4 (a grayscale image should have 1 channel). I'm not sure what color.WHITE/BLACK means for a grayscale image. Try using 255/0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [bitwise-not](https://docs.opencv.org/java/3.1.0/org/opencv/core/Core.html#bitwise_not-org.opencv.core.Mat-org.opencv.core.Mat-) to invert the image. In general, you want to avoid iterating through each pixel as it is very slow.

Original

[image]

Result

[image]

Here are two methods to invert an image. Using the built in `cv2.bitwise_not()` function or just subtracting 255. It's implemented in Python but the same idea can be used in Java.

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
result = 255 - image
alternative_result = cv2.bitwise_not(image)

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.imshow('alternative_result', alternative_result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input is a grayscale image. So only pure white will be turned to black, everything else will be white.

I'm not familiar with opencv, so this might not work. But it is worth a shot.

```
int invertedPixel = (0xFFFFFF - pixel) | 0xFF000000;
bitmapCopy.setPixel(x,y, invertedPixel);
```